# TicTacToe in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, tic-tac-toe

I have just started learning Python. This is code for a TicTacToe game. Can you please suggest any improvements?

```
pos_matrix=[[' ',' ',' '],[' ',' ',' '],[' ',' ',' ']]
def my_tictactoe(pos,symbol):
    if pos_matrix[pos[0]-1][pos[1]-1]!=' ':
        print('Invalid input')
        exit
    else:
        pos_matrix[pos[0]-1][pos[1]-1]=symbol
    for i in range(0,3):
        print(pos_matrix[i][0]+' | '+pos_matrix[i][1]+' | '+pos_matrix[i][2])
        print('--|---|--')

    if is_win():
        print('GAME OVER. \n Player with symbol {x} wins!'.format(x=pos_matrix[pos[0]-1][pos[1]-1]))
        for i in [0,1,2]:
            pos_matrix[i][0]=pos_matrix[i][1]=pos_matrix[i][2]=' '


def is_win():
    for i in [0,1,2]:
        if pos_matrix[i][0]==pos_matrix[i][1]==pos_matrix[i][2]!=' ':
            return True
        elif pos_matrix[0][i]==pos_matrix[1][i]==pos_matrix[2][i]!=' ':
            return True
    if pos_matrix[0][0]==pos_matrix[1][1]==pos_matrix[2][2]!=' ':
        return True
    elif pos_matrix[0][2]==pos_matrix[1][1]==pos_matrix[2][0]!=' ':
        return True
    else:
        return False


my_tictactoe((1,1),'o')
my_tictactoe((2,2),'x')
my_tictactoe((3,2),'o')
my_tictactoe((1,3),'x')
my_tictactoe((2,1),'o')
my_tictactoe((3,3),'x')
my_tictactoe((3,1),'o')
my_tictactoe((1,2),'x')
```

Answer (score 2):

PyLint is a useful tool for checking your code, ensuring good coding habits.  For example, PyLint doesn’t like a lack of spaces around operators or after commas.  Neither do my old weak eyes.  Instead of this:

```
pos_matrix=[[' ',' ',' '],[' ',' ',' '],[' ',' ',' ']]
```

... code like this:

```
pos_matrix = [[' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ']]
```

---

An `if` statement that does a `return` or `exit` doesn’t need to be followed by an `else` or `elif`; if the `if` statement is true, the execution path doesn’t need to skip around the `else` clause, because execution has already left the function.

For clarity:

```
if pos_matrix[pos[0]-1][pos[1]-1]!=' ':
    print('Invalid input')
    exit
else:
    pos_matrix[pos[0]-1][pos[1]-1]=symbol

for i in range(0,3):
    # print rows of game grid
```

After the `if-else` statement is the code to print out the game grid.  It appears this code belongs to both paths through the `if-else`, where as it will only execute if the `False` path is taken.  As such, it should be indented to belong as part of the `else:` clause:

```
if pos_matrix[pos[0] - 1][pos[1] - 1] != ' ':
    print('Invalid input')
    exit
else:
    pos_matrix[pos[0] - 1][pos[1] - 1] = symbol

    for i in range(0,3):
        # print rows of game grid
```

Alternately, the `else:` can be omitted entirely, and the statement in the `else:` clause outdented to the same level as the `if` statement:

```
if pos_matrix[pos[0]-1][pos[1]-1]!=' ':
    print('Invalid input')
    exit

pos_matrix[pos[0]-1][pos[1]-1]=symbol

for i in range(0,3):
    # print rows of game grid
```

---

Invalid input should not unconditionally terminate the program.

```
if pos_matrix[pos[0]-1][pos[1]-1]!=' ':
    print('Invalid input')
    exit
```

This code makes it harder to use in a larger program, since an invalid input will terminate the entire program.

Instead, a `ValueError` exception should be raised:

```
if pos_matrix[pos[0] - 1][pos[1] - 1] != ' ':
    raise ValueError('Invalid input')
```

This allows the caller to use a `try ... except:` structure.  The user could enter an invalid input, the function detects this and raises the error.  The caller catches the error, and request the user re-enter a valid move.

Without the appropriate `try ... except:` statement, raising the exception will also terminate the program.

---

You decode `pos` using `[pos[0]-1][pos[1]-1]` multiple times.  This is ugly and hard to follow.  Use variable names to avoid repeating the same calculations:

```
row, col = pos[0] - 1, pos[1] - 1
```

Then you can write:

```
if pos_matrix[row][col] != ' ':
```

---

Instead of looping over `range(0, 3)` or `[0, 1, 2]`, just use `range(3)`:

```
for i in range(3):
    ....
```

---

```
def my_tictactoe(pos,symbol):
    ...
    pos_matrix[pos[0]-1][pos[1]-1]=symbol
    ...
    print('GAME OVER. \n Player with symbol {x} wins!'.format(x=pos_matrix[pos[0]-1][pos[1]-1]))
```

Why the complex expression to set `x`in the format statement?  You’ve just assigned `symbol`to that pos_matrix entry; just use that!

```
print('GAME OVER. \n Player with symbol {x} wins!'.format(x=symbol))
```

Or better, if you are using python 3.6 or later, use an f-string:

```
print(f'GAME OVER. \n Player with symbol {symbol} wins!')
```

---

Your `is_win` code is more complex than needed because you are checking if anyone has won, which means a row, column or diagonal has 3 of the same symbol, which is not a space.  If you passed the symbol to the function, you can check if that player has won, which means checking for 3 of that symbol only, which is slightly shorter & simpler.

```
def is_win(symbol):
    for i in range(3):
        if all( pos_matrix[i][col] == symbol for col in range(3)):
            return True
        if all( pos_matrix[row][i] == symbol for row in range(3)):
            return True
    if all( pos_matrix[i][i] == symbol for i in range(3)):
        return True
    if all( pos_matrix[i][2 - i] == symbol for i in range(3)):
        return True
    return False
```

---

Who's turn is it, anyway?

You call `my_tictactoe(...)` and pass in the character to place in the grid.  As Hack Saw pointed out, this could be a `'p'`!

Instead, it would be better for the game to keep track of who's turn it is, and automatically use the appropriate symbol.

For example, you could set a global `symbol` variable initially to `'x'`, and then have it flip between `'x'` and `'o'` after processing a valid move.

```
symbol = 'x'

def my_tictactoe(pos):

    # ... existing validation, printing, and win detection code ...

    # Alternate players: 'x' <--> 'o'
    symbol = 'o' if symbol == 'x' else 'x'
```

As a bonus, after one player wins, the other player will automatically become the first player.

---

To test the program, with the automatic player tracking, (expanding on Hack Saw's suggestion a bit) the test code could become:

```
def main():

    for pos in ((1,1), (2,2), (3,2), (1,3), (2,1), (3,3), (3,1), (1,2)):
        my_tictactoe(pos)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: To your second point: I would still use an `else` statement even if it is not required, just to make it easier to read (as long as this doesn't add to many indentations.) This is simple because some people jump to the end of the function to see what is returns, and they then think, it always returns that, what may not be true.

Comment: @MegaIng I've clarified my point a bit.

Answer (score 1):

What if someone tries `my_tictactoe((1,2),'p')?`

In addition, a python thing: You can have a main function to turn this into a module of sorts.

At the end of the file, you would add:

```
def main():
    #test game here


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

You could put your test game in there. That way, you could call your functions from another file to use it as a library, or run it on its own as a module test.

Comment: I didn't know about that. Thank you :)